# Can't remote query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powershell, networking

We're trying to run a remote query from PS to one of our SQL Server databases. Running the script returns an error

> SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

If we run the script directly on the SQL Server, it runs successfully. We can ping the server successfully.

So far we've done the following:

- Verified all SQL services are running.
- Ensured remote access was allowed within SQL Server Management Studio
- Checked to make sure SQL browser was running and set to automatic.
- Turned the firewall completely off on both the server and workstation (reenabled after that test failed).

Remote queries used to work for us without any issues. No notable changes were made that would have caused this issue that we're aware of.

Comment: Check port connectivity. Is this a named instance?

Comment: _error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified_ sounds like an instance name resolution error. When using instance names in connection strings the client first uses the SQL Server Resolution Protocol to query the SQL Browser service over udp/1434, then uses the tcp port number that was returned to connect to the SQL Server instance. Both udp/1434 and the instance's tcp port number need to be accessible through network firewalls (and Windows Firewall). If you've just installed the instance, or changed the instance network configuration, you must restart SQL Browser to detect changes.

Comment: Yeah the instance is named. This is the PS command we're running that used to be successful: Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database "name" -Query "select p.first_name, p.last_name, p.full_name, p.primary_email, c.serial_num from computers c, persons p where c.computer_name like '%name%' and c.owner_id = p.id" -ServerInstance "SQLSERVER\DB".

Comment: I ran a TCP connection test from the work station to the assigned port for the database and it was successful just as an update.